# How to set sendAsEmail via Google's Gmail api

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I'm updating a PHP application to create new email accounts in Google (using the Google Directory Service). I have no problem creating the account, but so far I've been unable to use the Google Gmail Service to set the sendAsEmail attribute (so that the alias will show up in the "From"). Also, var_dump($createSendAsResult) in the snippet below does not produce any output. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!
Here's my code:

```
//Create account in Google                                                   
function createGoogleAccount($server_name, $acc_user, $acc_password)                                                                                                           
{                                                                                                                                                                                 
    $clientDir = getClientDir($server_name);                                                                                                                                           
    $dirService = new Google_Service_Directory($clientDir);                                                                                                                            

    $userInstance = new Google_Service_Directory_User();                                                                                                                               
    $nameInstance = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();                                                                                                                           

    $nameInstance -> setGivenName('Generic');                                                                                                                                          
    $nameInstance -> setFamilyName($acc_user);                                                                                                                                         

    $userInstance -> setOrgUnitPath("/generic_email");                                                                                                                                 
    $userInstance -> setName($nameInstance);                                                                                                                                           
    $userInstance -> setHashFunction("MD5");                                                                                                                                           
    $domain = getDomain($server_name);                                                                                                                                                 
    $primary_email = $acc_user . '@' . $domain;                                                                                                                                        
    $userInstance -> setPrimaryEmail($primary_email);                                                                                                                                  
    $userInstance -> setPassword(hash("md5", $acc_password));                                                                                                                          
    $optParams = array( );                                                                                                                                                             

    $error_msg = null;                                                                                                                                                                 
    try                                                                                                                                                                                
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $createUserResult = $dirService->users->insert($userInstance, $optParams);                                                                                                 
            var_dump($createUserResult);                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  
    catch (Google_IO_Exception $gioe)                                                                                                                                                  
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $error_msg =  "Error in connection: ".$gioe->getMessage();                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  
    catch (Google_Service_Exception $gse)                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $error_msg = "Service Exception: ".$gse->getMessage();                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  

    addSendAs($server_name, $acc_user, $domain);                                                                                                      return $error_msg;                                                                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                                                                          
function addSendAs($server_name, $acc_user, $domain)                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                          
    $clientGmail = getClientGmail($server_name);                                                                                                                                       
    $gmailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($clientGmail);                                                                                                                            
    $primary_email = $acc_user . '@' . $domain;                                                                                                                                        
    $sendAsEmail = new Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs();                                                                                                                                  

    $alias = '';                                                                                                                                                                       
    if (($server_name == null) || (strpos($server_name, "dev") != false))                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $alias = '@g.';                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  
    else                                                                                                                                                                               
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $alias = '@mail.';                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  

    $sendAsEmail -> setSendAsEmail($acc_user . $alias . $domain);                                                                                                                      
    $sendAsEmail -> setIsDefault(TRUE);                                                                                                                                                
    $sendAsEmail -> setIsPrimary(TRUE);                                                                                                                                                

    $error_msg = null;                                                                                                                                                                 
    try                                                                                                                                                                                
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $createSendAsResult = $gmailService->users_settings_sendAs -> create($primary_email, $sendAsEmail);                                                                        
            var_dump($createSendAsResult);                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  
    catch (Google_IO_Exception $gioe)                                                                                                                                                  
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $error_msg =  "Error in connection: ".$gioe->getMessage();                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                  
    catch (Google_Service_Exception $gse)                                                                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                                                                                  
            $error_msg = "Service Exception: ".$gse->getMessage();                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Well, if I try to set this `sendAsEmail` attribute using the Try it part of the Gmail API, I receive an error 403 `"Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority"` I found out in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/a185jwNyDlM) that the meaning of this error is that "The initial account must have Admin or Super Admin delegation to operate in the admin control panel, where you then grant an account  addition rights (delegation)."

Comment: Since my initial post, I made some code changes, including the addition of an error_log() statement to output the exception messages. (Most of my programming experience is in Java, but I'm required to use php for this project, so I'm still getting used to it.) This account does have domain-wide authorization and the access scope includes everything for Gmail. Here's the error that I get:  Service Exception: {\n "error": {\n  "errors": [\n   {\n    "domain": "global",\n    "reason": "forbidden",\n    "
message": "Delegation denied for generic_test_svc@sandbox.xxx.edu"\n   }\n  ],\n ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after much experimentation with the code and some help from a couple of colleagues, I figured out what the problem is and how to solve it.

Apparently, Google needs time to set up a new user's account with email.  When I added a 10-second delay - sleep(10) in php - that was sufficient for the account to be ready for calls to the Gmail API, including the creation of a SendAs alias.

Comment: As in real life, the solution is sleep. :)